# Running initialization python on import of a pybind11 library

Tags: python, import, initialization, pybind11

I have a pybind11 library built with class and functions defined in it. I need to call some python to initialize python paths etc when it's imported...

```
import my_pybind11

# I would like it to causes my_init to be called...
# if it were straight python I would just put 

def my_init():
    sys.paths.append('hope/you/can/help')

my_init()

# in the body of the library source.
```

I'm unsure how to get the same effect when using a pybind11 library which is mostly c++ & a binding.

Comment: Were you need to add root paths to the file?

Comment: Not specifically, just an example of what you might do.

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#executing-python-code | And `PYBIND11_MODULE` creates the function that's called when your module is imported...

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. I have read that page but it's still not clear to me how to create a module, some defined in C++ and some in python. The wrapper I used works but I would be interested if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I took the approach of renaming the pybind11 C++ wrapped library to
_my_pybind11

and added a my_pybind11.py:

```
from _my_pybind11 import *

def my_init():
    sys.paths.append('hope/you/can/help')

my_init()
```

That allowed me to bundle some pure python with the pybind11 built c++ lib.